# Thread throws error message---eclipse Android

Tags: android, eclipse

Where timer is a textview and throws error during runtime.

```
[Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache]
[Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()]
```

Plz help.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level_twolayout);

    t1 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 50; i>= 0; i--) {
                        try {
           error------> Timer.setText(i);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };t1.start();
}
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9XCY.png
```

Comment: can you paste the full error message?

Comment: I have attached the error link above plz help trying  for 2 days not able to find the error.

Comment: i tried but not able to reproduce the error what you told.. i have one sample code which will update textview inside the thread .. its working fine for me .. you want to try that one? becasue with your code i am getting CalledFromWrongThreadException:

Comment: S sure can u mail me to gvprasad000@gmail.com

Comment: Sure can I get the code that u have..

Comment: hope so this will help you

Answer (score 0):

try with this one:

```
TextView Timer;
int i ;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    Timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    final int length = 50;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (  i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Timer.setText(new Integer(i).toString());
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    }
```